# How do I do pivoting in this query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table like this:

```
Name; Amount1, Amount, Rate1, Rate2
Test; 1000; 2000; 1.0; 2.0
```

I want to display into:

```
Parameter; Amount1; Rate1; Total
'Parameter 1'; 1000; 1.0; 1000 
'Parameter 2'; 2000; 2.0; 4000
```

BTW ... I am using SQL2K5. All I can think of is CURSOR. Any other solution in elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, Amount*rate Total from( 
select n parameter, case when n='parameter1' then amount1 else amount2 end Amount,
       case when n='parameter1' then rate1 else rate2 end rate
from tests t cross join (select 'parameter1' as n union all select 'parameter2') x
) y
```